# Artificial Neural Network Example Problem

Tags: algorithms, homework, self-study

I was looking at an example of a NN but I dont understand in the Answer i where the .68 come from or .6637 [image]

This is the [link](https://www4.rgu.ac.uk/files/chapter3%20-%20bp.pdf) of the tutorial

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The tutorial states that each neuron uses the [sigmoid activation function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sigmoid_function):

[image]

That funciton is:
$$
\sigma(x) = \frac{1}{1+ e^{-x}}
$$
so j[ust substitute $x = 0.755$ into that to get](https://www.google.com/search?q=exp(-0.755)&oq=exp(-0.755)&aqs=chrome..69i57.10343j0j4&sourceid=chrome&es_sm=119&ie=UTF-8#q=1%2F(1%2Bexp(-0.755))) 0.68026719669.